# How to publish KTable changes as new events in another topic with spring-kafka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using spring-kafka I want to publish the result (?) of the `KTable` as a new event into another topic, but the stream for **topicB** never receives events.

The same seems to happen, if I call `mapValues()` on the `KTable` directly. What am I missing to work with the content of `KTable`?

```
@Bean
KTable reportStream(StreamsBuilder builder, Engine engine) {

    def stream = builder.stream("topicA")
            .groupBy({ key, word -> word })
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)))
            .aggregate(
            new Initializer<Long>() {
                @Override
                Long apply() {
                    0
                }
            },
            new Aggregator<String, String, Long>() {
                @Override
                Long apply(String key, String value, Long aggregate) {
                    def l = 1 + aggregate
                    return l
                }
            },
            new Merger() {
                @Override
                Long apply(Object aggKey, Object aggOne, Object aggTwo) {
                    return aggOne + aggTwo
                }
            },
            Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))

    stream.toStream().to("topicB")
    stream
}

@Bean
KStream classificationStream(StreamsBuilder builder, Engine engine) {

    builder.stream("topicB").mapValues({
        println "topicB"
        println it
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code is actually telling Kafka Streams to start the data processing?  Without the Spring abstraction layer, you'd typically have code like `KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config); streams.start();` in your Java/Scala application.

Comment: Well, plus `KafkaStreams#start()` -- but I would assume that Spring-Kafka handles this? Other question: how long did you wait? Maybe we need to disable caching: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html One more question: do you have `null` key or values in you input data? Those would be dropped silently.

Comment: I definitely receive events for **topicA** and they are processed correctly (I've debugged and printed stuff in the `aggregate` block). Also, when I change the code to omit any grouping stuff and only do `map({ ... }).to("topicB")` everything works correctly. I waited 20 seconds.

Comment: But the keys of the original input are `null`, thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into this.

Comment: The setting `commit.interval.ms` is 30 seconds.  Perhaps wait a bit longer?  Could it be that you don't have a lot of data flowing in, which could mean that Kafka Streams would only send updates once `commit.interval.ms` has passed (rather than sending updates earlier because cache pressure hit, cf. `cache.max.bytes.buffering`).  See "Record caches in the DSL" at https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#id1.

Comment: Yes, it's an integration test setup with very limited data. That's a good information, I'll check this out tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: Starting and stopping the `KafkaStreams` instance should be handled automatically by Spring Kafka as part of the general Spring application lifecycle. At this point, I would take Michael and Matthias' recommendations to look into Kafka Streams specific stuff. However, a complete working example that reproduces this would be helpful.

Comment: Worked after waiting for the commit (or reducing the interval), thanks for the help. I'll try to edit the question a bit further and add a more useful solution (was also missing some more Serdes).